# GitHub changed to BitBucket when doing git push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have both GitHub and BitBucket accounts, but I only use GitHub one. Only a few days ago when I got the client with the BitBucket repo, I've decided to try it out and have installed SourceTree, pulled a repo there and everything was ok. The problem occurred when I went on the project which was on my GitHub repo. I made changes, and with console did `add` and`commit`, and when I wrote `git push` this came out:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

So I figured I'd run the `git config --global push.default matching` command and try again. After that I got a message saying:

```
Password for 'https://xyz@bitbucket.org':
```

where `xyz` isn't even my username or username of shared repo users on BitBucket

So My question is how did that happen, and how can I revert this to push on my GitHub repo?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` inside your repo?

Comment: `origin  https://xyz@bitbucket.org/xyz/project_name.git (push)`

Comment: Oh, it might be that I pulled the `.git` from server which was pointing to another repository...can I change it to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `git remote -v` output in comment of OP:

> $ git remote -v
>   origin https://xyz@bitbucket.org/xyz/project_name.git (push)

`git remote -v` is linked to your BitBucket repository. You need to change/set `origin` with GitHub URL.

```
$ git remote set-url origin <github-repo-url>

# make sure 'origin' is updated
$ git remote -v
```